# What is this seemingly base64 data set by setfattr?

Tags: xattr, base64

I have written a short shell script that simply wraps `setfattr` in a slightly more convenient form for setting the extended attribute that corresponds to a free-text comment:

```
#!/bin/sh
test "$2" && setfattr -n user.xdg.comment -v "$2" "$1"
getfattr -d -m '^user.xdg.comment$' "$1"
```

For storing US ASCII comments as xattrs, this works great. However, if I try to set a comment that contains non US ASCII characters, it gives me back what appears to be Base64 encoded data:

```
$ touch xyz
$ set-comment xyz åäöåä
# file: xyz
user.xdg.comment=0sw6XDpMO2w6XDpA==
$
```

But it isn't just Base64:

```
$ printf "0sw6XDpMO2w6XDpA==" | \base64 --decode
��:\:L;l:\:@base64: invalid input
$
```

Most of the time, I get *just* random-looking garbage back. Some times, like this, the Base64 decoder throws "invalid input" back at me.

**What is this string?** What is its relationship to the original input value? How do I go from what `getfattr` gives me back to the original input value (such as `åäöåä` in this case)?

`setfattr --version` on my system responds with `setfattr 2.4.46`. I'm running the version packaged by Debian Wheezy. In the unlikely event that it matters, I'm running ZFS On Linux 0.6.3 (saw the same behavior with 0.6.2 as well) on the stock Wheezy kernel.

Comment: What about `echo -n "...."`. The `echo` will include an extra `\n` on you when you pipe that to base64.

Comment: @slm s/echo/printf/ gives the exact same result, as far as I can tell. And the final newline *shouldn't* matter for base64 decoding. Still a good point; I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a bit curious reading this questoion, so let’s do some *“forensics”*:

## First trying the opposite:

How is `åäöåä` encoded in Base64?

```
$ echo åäöåä | base64
w6XDpMO2w6XDpAo=
```

This clearly looks a lot like the `0sw6XDpMO2w6XDpA==` that you’ve got. There’s an extra `0s` at the beginning, and the end doesn’t exactly match. Suppressing the newline at the end of `åäöåä` (automatically inserted by `echo`), we get:

```
$ echo -n åäöåä | base64
w6XDpMO2w6XDpA==
```

This is exactly the `user.xdg.comment`-value except the `0s` at the start.

## Conclusion

The comment *is* Base64 encoded and prefixed with `0s`, and testing a few other strings confirms this.

*Example:*

```
$ ./set-comment xyz 日本語
# file: xyz
user.xdg.comment=0s5pel5pys6Kqe

$ base64 -d <<<'5pel5pys6Kqe' ; echo
日本語
```

*(where the `; echo` is to not mess up the next prompt since the output of `base64` does not end in a new-line.)*

***However...***

This just shows that in these cases (where the comment is non-ASCII), it gets encoded in Base64 and prefixed with `0s`.

## The “real” answer

After doing this I got the splendid idea of checking the man-page for `getfattr` and it mentions, among other things:

**Regarding th option `-e en, --encoding=en`**

> Encode  values  after retrieving them.  Valid values of en are "text", "hex", and "base64".  Values encoded as text strings are enclosed in double quotes ("), while strings encoded as hexidecimal and base64 are prefixed with 0x and 0s, respectively.

So, changing your script to:

(File **set-comment**:)

```
#!/bin/sh
test "$2" && setfattr -n user.xdg.comment -v "$2" "$1"
getfattr -e text -d -m '^user.xdg.comment$' "$1"
```

will always print the attribute as text, giving, for example:

```
$ ./set-comment xyz åäöåä   # with fixed script
# file: xyz
user.xdg.comment="åäöåä"
```

However, there is still some caveats left... like:

```
$ ./set-comment xyz 0x414243
# file: xyz
user.xdg.comment="ABC"
```

and

```
$ ./set-comment xyz 0s5pel5pys6Kqe
# file: xyz
user.xdg.comment="日本語"
```

where the output doesn’t match the input.

These can be fixed by “massaging” the argument into a form that `setfattr` likes. See `man setfattr`.

Comment: If anyone wants to edit this answer to just include the “answer” bit at the end, it’s OK by me. ... I had written the whole “forensics” bit before I got to the “read the man-page and find the answer” bit, so I didn’t just want to throw it away right away... It also shows some methods to how to find an answer when you have a “feeling” of what it should be, but it doesn’t match exactly...

Comment: Perfect! And please do keep this the way it is. I can live with 0x and 0s being special cases; since they are printed right back at me, anything that ends up being interpreted in the "wrong" way will be caught quickly anyway.